# memcache 1.2.2 versus 1.4.7 log messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached

The following log output on memcached 1.2.2:

```
<8 new client connection
<8 set mynamespace:views/show 0 47 20499
>8 STORED
```

can be interpreted as, expires_in = 47 seconds and size = 20499.

How do we interpret the following memcached 1.4.7 log output for expires_in and size?

```
<40 GET views/show
>40 Writing an error: Not found  
>40 Writing bin response:  
>40   0x81 0x00 0x00 0x00  
>40   0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01  
>40   0x00 0x00 0x00 0x09  
>40   0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00  
>40   0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00  
>40   0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00  
<40 Read binary protocol data:  
<40    0x80 0x01 0x00 0x38  
<40    0x08 0x00 0x00 0x00  
<40    0x00 0x00 0x00 0x46  
<40    0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00  
<40    0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00  
<40    0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00  
<40 SET views/show Value len is 6  
>40 Writing bin response:  
>40   0x81 0x01 0x00 0x00  
>40   0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00  
>40   0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00  
>40   0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00  
>40   0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00  
>40   0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
```

Comment: It seems like you're trying to do something that could be done more easily a different way.  I don't think logging the protocol stream is the best way to do something if it's not actually watch and understand the protocol stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/memcached/memcached/blob/master/memcached.c

search for "settings.verbose"  Or you can search for "Writing bin response" and it will show you the actual code.

Memcache++ open source code!